# distorted map image when using react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Map, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';

export default class PageBackground extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.getLocation=this.getLocation.bind(this);
        this.state={
            position:[2,2]
        };
        }


    componentWillMount() {
        this.getLocation();
    }
    getLocation () {

        fetch('http://freegeoip.net/json/')
         .then((res)=>res.json())
         .then((objec)=>{this.setState({position:[objec.latitude,objec.longitude]});console.log(this.state.position)})
         .catch((err)=>{console.log("didn't connect to App",err);this.setState({position:['10','8']});})
    }

    render(){
        return (
      <Map center={this.state.position} zoom={13} >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'/>

        </Map>
        );
        }
    }
```

My aim to make the map stretch over a height of 100px and a width of 100px so i wrote this css style:

```
.leaflet-container {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

Now,the problem is that leaflet is returning a distorted image.what am i doing wrong?
[image: Distorted image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'` to my component got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Check your tiles size, all tiles should be at 256x256 px
or
You can use sharp (nodejs) to make tiles and adding some margin to your original image file
or
You can disable Leaflet CSS inline Styles with height and width to auto (!important)

http://sharp.dimens.io/en/stable/api-output/#tile

```
const leaftletsize = { width: 34000, height: 34000 };
const left = (leaftletsize.width - mymap.width) / 2;
const top = (leaftletsize.height - mymap.height) / 2;
extendto = ({ left, top, right: left, bottom: top });

const createTiles = (extendto) => {
    const outputtilesdir = path.join(outputpath, 'sharp');
    console.log(`Create tiles to ${outputtilesdir}`);
    const tilesconfig = { size: 256, layout: 'dz' };
    const extrabackground = {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, alpha: 1};
    return sharp(originalmapfile)
        .limitInputPixels(false)
        .background(extrabackground)
        .extend(extendto)
        .png()
        .tile(tilesconfig)
        .toFile(outputtilesdir);
    };
```